# How do you divide a register in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, divide, arithmetic-expressions

Please forgive me for a stupid syntax question, but I have two variables (squares and horizCharsPerSquare) and I'm trying to set the ecx equal to squares/horizCharsPerSquare. I've tried:

```
    mov ecx, squares/horizCharsPerSquare
```

and

```
    mov ecx squares
    div horizCharsPerSquare
```

and

```
    mov ecx, squares
    shr ecx, horizCharsPerSquare ;//(I know there are other issues with this, I was just giving it a shot
```

And no matter what, I get an error? I get build errors that "constant is expected" for everything. Any suggestions for how I should do this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieuUHIWaIqM&index=19&list=PL0C5C980A28FEE68D  7:15

Comment: `mov ecx, squares/horizCharsPerSquare` would work if those were both assemble-time constants.  A right-shift is the correct choice if `horizCharsPerSquare` is a power of 2.  `mov ecx squares` would assemble, but that's [not how `div` works](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html).  See also the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both *squares* and *horizCharsPerSquare* are variables, you normally would move them to registers before doing arithmetic on them. **Here** only the first variable needs to be moved to a register because the `div` instruction does allow for a memory operand:

```
mov eax, squares
xor edx, edx
div horizCharsPerSquare  ;Divide EDX:EAX by the dword variable
mov ecx, eax             ;Put quotient in ECX
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I was having so much trouble with that